# Spring LogoutSuccessHandler not invoked

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot (1.3.5) + oauth2 (spring-cloud-starter-oauth2). I would like to test some [LogoutSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html) but I'm unable to invoke it.

This is my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .anonymous().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/resources/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessHandler(logoutHandler);
        //.invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "SESSION");
    }
}
```

This is my logoutHandler

```
@Component
public class LogoutHandler extends AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
        super.handle(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

When I debug the application and put the breakpoint to the logoutHandler it's never invoked. Am I missing something in this configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update your `configure` method a little bit. You don't have to use `AntPathRequestMatcher` to match logout url.

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .anonymous().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/resources/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutHandler)
            //.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "JSESSIONID")
            //.invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll();
    }
```

Comment: Even if I try your suggestion it doesn't work :( Weird thing is that, when I send post to localhost:8080/ui/logout I'm getting error GET http://localhost:8080/ui/login?logout 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Why do you need  the `@Order`? Can you remove it and try?